# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, google-visualization, undefined, labjs

Trying to use google charts in chart point while loading the resources through LABjs.

I keep getting the error that DataTable is undefined.

This is what I used to load LABjs:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true">
    <Scripts>
        <%-- Script Manager -Kessy Dec9/13 --%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/libs/LAB.min.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference><asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/libs/scriptloader.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

LABjs:

```
$LAB
    .script("/Style Library/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js").wait()
    .script("/Style Library/libs/jquery-ui.min.js")
    .script("/Style Library/libs/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js")
    .script("/Style Library/libs/angular.min.js")
    .script("/Style Library/libs/knockout-3.0.0.js")
    .script("/Style Library/addons/wpToggle/wpToggle-jQuery.js")
    .script("https://www.google.com/jsapi").wait()
    .script("/Style Library/addons/spCharts/spjs-charts-v4.js")
    .script("/Style Library/addons/quickLaunchToggle/jQuery.LISP.quicklaunch.js")
    .script("/Style Library/addons/digitalClock/digitalClock.js");
```

jQuery is the first call and nothing else runs before it, then I call other things after that jsapi and make sure charts isn't called before jsapi. It works fine when it's all loading within the sharepoint aspx file but I want to use LAB to manage my scripts better.

The error:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Do you call `google.load` to load the Visualization API?

Comment: @asgallant beat me to it. This is the message you get when the library isn't `google.load`ed, and it doesn't know what a DataTable is.

Comment: I'm not really sure. I think the HTML renders first with a div for the chart. Then the google/jsapi and after that a script to generate the charts.